# ExtJS 4.2 layout crush on latest chrome but not on old one in full screen

Tags: extjs, extjs4, geoext

I've noticed that only in chrome my GeoExt app crush when I open many layers.
If I resize the window , the layout seems to look good , once I resize to bigger screen , it mess again.

The app code didn't change for long time , it doesn't happen on old laptop with chrome version 27 it only happens on 2 stronger desktops with latest chrome version.

any idea (bottom picture is same screen from top picture but on full screen) ?!

[image]

[image]